# Dart Web "transitive libraries have sdk dependencies that not supported on this platform"

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I've had an Angular-Dart web app I've been working on for a while, which suddenly has stopped compiling. I've not made any changes to my code since the last successful compile, although I did update the SDK and ran `pub upgrade` to update the dependencies for the newer SDK version.

I get the following warning when I use `pub run build_runner serve`:

```
[WARNING] build_web_compilers:entrypoint on web/main.dart:
Skipping compiling dbClient|web/main.dart with ddc because some of its
transitive libraries have sdk dependencies that not supported on this platform:

analyzer|lib/src/lint/project.dart
analyzer|lib/file_system/physical_file_system.dart
analyzer|lib/src/summary/package_bundle_reader.dart
analyzer|lib/src/dart/sdk/sdk.dart
analyzer|lib/src/lint/linter.dart
analyzer|lib/src/lint/util.dart
analyzer|lib/src/lint/io.dart
analyzer|lib/src/lint/analysis.dart
glob|lib/glob.dart
glob|lib/src/list_tree.dart
front_end|lib/src/api_prototype/terminal_color_support.dart
front_end|lib/src/fasta/crash.dart
front_end|lib/src/fasta/colors.dart
front_end|lib/src/base/processed_options.dart
front_end|lib/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart
front_end|lib/src/compute_platform_binaries_location.dart
kernel|lib/transformations/constants.dart
kernel|lib/kernel.dart
kernel|lib/binary/ast_to_binary.dart
watcher|lib/src/directory_watcher/windows.dart
watcher|lib/src/directory_watcher.dart
watcher|lib/src/directory_watcher/linux.dart
watcher|lib/src/file_watcher/native.dart
watcher|lib/src/file_watcher.dart
watcher|lib/src/directory_watcher/mac_os.dart
watcher|lib/src/stat.dart
watcher|lib/src/file_watcher/polling.dart
watcher|lib/src/constructable_file_system_event.dart
watcher|lib/watcher.dart
watcher|lib/src/directory_watcher/polling.dart
watcher|lib/src/utils.dart
analyzer|lib/src/util/sdk.dart
analyzer|lib/src/generated/java_io.dart
analyzer|lib/src/generated/java_engine_io.dart
source_gen|lib/src/type_checker.dart

https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-resolve-skipped-compiling-warnings
```

I've researched the issue, and it seems most people run into this issue when they try and use libraries that don't support web, like `dart:io`. That is not the case here so far as I can tell. I'm not particularly familiar with those libraries, and I have not directly depended on any of them, but theoretically as far as I can tell all the libraries I have directly depended on support web. Or at least they used to...

Based on the link in the warning message, I updated build.yaml to look like the following:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      angular_components|scss_builder:
        enabled: True
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        generate_for:
        - web/**.dart
```

The dependencies section in pubspec.yaml looks like this:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.2.0'

dependencies:
  spiderman_shared:
    path: ../shared
  angular: '>=5.2.0'
  angular_forms: '>=2.1.0'
  angular_router: '>=2.0.0-alpha+15'
  angular_components: '>=0.12.0'
  decimal: '>=0.3.2'
  date_calendar:
    path: ../../date_calendar_2
  markdown: ^2.0.2
  color: ^2.1.1
  couchdb: 
    path: ../../couchdb


dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: '>=2.0.0-beta'
  build_runner: '>=1.5.0 <2.0.0'
  build_test: '>=0.10.2'
  build_web_compilers: '>=1.2.0 <3.0.0'
```

I'm thoroughly confounded by this issue. I've been trying to figure it out in my spare time for probably a month or two now, but now I've reached the point where I need to make some important changes to the app and really need to get it resolved. Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: have you try to build it with `dart2js`, for example with `webdev serve --release` like the example on this page https://dart.dev/tools/webdev

Comment: Did Google change the build process again? Seems they like doing that. Anyway I just gave webdev a try though, and it gives me word-for-word the exact same error message as build_runner did.

Comment: I'm not sure about the error, but I just saw on your error about ddc (which means using dartdevc, build for development), sometimes I try to build using dart2js (for example with add `--release`) to find another alternative, and add verbosity output.